# C# setters for INT

Tags: c#, int, setter

As I have already done, I have this piece of code:

```
 private string opt;// create a property
        public string optionInterval
        {
            get
            {
                return opt;
            }
            set
            {
                opt = value;
            }
        }
```

How can I change the opt to an integer?
Especially in the set part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public int optionInterval { get; set; }
```

Using [**Auto-Implemented Properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

---

Here's a working version of GianT971's answer:

```
    private int opt; 
    public string optionInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return opt.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            opt = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
        private int opt; 
        public string optionInterval
        {
            get
            {
                return opt.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                opt = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sure it does. I do this all the time

Comment: If optionInterval is taken from a file for example, it is a string value. Then you tell the program that when you assign optionInterval, you want actually to set the private int opt variable (you use Convert.ToInt32 for this purpose). And when you want to retrieve it, you return the int opt value converted to a string with ToString

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is not a type though, I think you meant `Convert.ToInt32(value)`

Comment: @agam360 Sorry you were right, I updated the code and now it will work